# Gradle duplicate entry

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, android-min-sdk

I have a problem when I update my application bat if I leave minSdkVersion to 15, I cannot generate a signed apk because I receive this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/database/DatabaseUtilsCompat.class

When `minSdkVersion` set to 25, there is no problem.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Inside libs folder i found a library that create a duplicate. The library was "android-support-v4.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `dependencies` entry:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your code not solve my problem. Console show me the same error